# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with Spring Boot 2.3 + Security only at the server

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx, spring-security

I'm trying to enable CORS with Spring Boot 2.3 and Spring Security working with an Angular frontend and I'm getting this error:

```java
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com.br/login' from origin 'https://app.example.com.br' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In the beginning CORS isn't working with both running local, so I tried different solutions:

1 - Create a corsConfigurationSource() like the docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#cors

2 - And now I created like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("Authorization", "Program", "authorization",
                "Content-Type", "User-Agent", "Origin", "X-XSRF-TOKEN")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
    }

}
```

My WebSecurityConfiguration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/favicon.ico", "/**/*.png", "/**/*.gif", "/**/*.svg", "/**/*.jpg", "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Now it's working when the frontend and the backend is running at the localhost.

**But when I deploy the backend at the server, the CORS still not working.**

```
Front and Back at Local = OK
Front Local and Back Server = Not Working
Front Server and Back Server = Not Working
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that once you add Spring Security into the mix, the `@CrossOrigin` annotation stops working. A filter usually solves the problem for me. This one is written in Kotlin.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication {

    @Value("#{ @environment['allowed.origins'] ?: {} }")
    private lateinit var allowedOrigins: List<String>

    @Bean
    fun simpleCorsFilter(): FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> {
        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        val config = CorsConfiguration()
        config.allowCredentials = true
        config.allowedOrigins = allowedOrigins
        config.allowedMethods = listOf("*");
        config.allowedHeaders = listOf("*")
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config)
        val bean = FilterRegistrationBean(CorsFilter(source))
        bean.order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE
        return bean
    }
}
```

A friend, Micah Silverman, solved it another way.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Value("#{ @environment['allowed.origins'] ?: {} }")
    private List<String> allowedOrigins;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

For the 2nd example, you need `http.cors().and()` in your Spring Security configuration.

For both, you can configure the allowed origins in `application.properties`:

```
allowed.origins=http://localhost:4200,https://production.url.com
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I appreciate your attention, but it doesn't work. My problem is when my API is deployed in a server. I already make it work at localhost.